# How to hide In-Store Pickup Shipping method on checkout based on certain conditions

Tags: checkout, shipping-methods, msi, store-pickup, instore-pickup

I am trying to hide In-Store Pickup on checkout page if certain conditions met.

For example, I need to hide In-Store Pickup on checkout shipping methods section if customer belongs to specific customer group. For this, I found the following function to plugin:

> Magento\InventoryInStorePickupShipping\Model\IsInStorePickupDeliveryAvailableForCart.php::execute()

[image]

But when I try to send false from this function, even then it still keep showing In-Store pickup method on checkout.

Please suggest which method I should override or plugin to hide In-store Pickup method on checkout.

Answer (score 0):

**Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateCollectorInterface">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="rateCollectorsList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="[vendor_Module]_shipping_method_restriction" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\Quote\ShippingMethodRestriction</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Vendor\Module\Model\Quote\ShippingMethodRestriction.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Quote;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateCollectorInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method;

class ShippingMethodRestriction implements RateCollectorInterface
{
    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return Method[]
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        // Get the current customer group ID
        $customerGroupId = $request->getQuote()->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
        
        // Get the shipping methods available in the request
        $methods = $request->getShippingMethods();
        
        // Check if the current customer group is the one you want to hide the In-Store Pickup method for
        if ($customerGroupId == customer_group_id) { //add customer group id
            // Loop through the available shipping methods and remove the In-Store Pickup method
            foreach ($methods as $key => $method) {
                if ($method->getMethodCode() == 'in_store_pickup') {
                    unset($methods[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return $methods;
    }
}
```

**Let me know if you facing any issues.**

**Thanks**

Comment: Hi @Ronak, thanks for suggesting this solution. I tried but seems it is not triggering. CollectRates method is not called.

Answer (score 0):

I plugin the Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping::collectRates() method after getting the hint from the solution provided by @Ronak Rathod. Here is the solution that is working fine for me.

In Module di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping">
        <plugin name="in_store_pickup_shipping_method_hide" type="Vendor\InStorePickup\Plugin\AfterShippingCollectRates"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And Code for my plugin is as follow.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\InStorePickup\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest as RateRequest;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class AfterShippingCollectRates
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected LoggerInterface $_logger;

    /**
     * @var ErrorFactory
     */
    private $rateErrorFactory;

    /**
     * @var RateRequest|null
     */
    private $request = null;

    public function __construct(
        ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->rateErrorFactory = $rateErrorFactory;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param Shipping $subject
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeCollectRates(
        Shipping $subject,
        RateRequest $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param Shipping $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return Shipping
     * @throws LocalizedException
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function afterCollectRates(Shipping $subject, $result)
    {
        $result = $subject->getResult();
        $rates = $result->getAllRates();
        $result->reset();
        foreach ($rates as $rate) {
            $restrict = false;
            if ($rate->getCarrier() == 'instore') {
                $checkIfStorePickupNeedtoBeHidden = $this->checkIfStorePickupNeedtoBeHidden();
                if ($checkIfStorePickupNeedtoBeHidden) {
                    $restrict = true;
                    $this->setError($result, $rate);
                }
            }
            if (!$restrict) {
                $result->append($rate);
            }
        }
        return $subject;
    }

    /**
     * set error message
     * @param Result $result
     * @param Method $rate
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function setError($result, $rate)
    {
        $errorMessage = __('Sorry, Pick in Store method is restricted for this Orders.');
        if ($rate !== null && $errorMessage) {
            $error = $this->rateErrorFactory->create();
            $error->setCarrier($rate->getCarrier());
            $error->setCarrierTitle($rate->getCarrierTitle().' ('.$rate->getMethodTitle().')');
            $error->setErrorMessage($errorMessage);
            $result->append($error);
        }
    }
}
```

Write down a custom function

> checkIfStorePickupNeedtoBeHidden

in the same file (or Helper) and put the logic for hiding shipping method in it.

Reference: https://webkul.com/blog/restrict-custom-shipping-methods-magento2/